# Как установить *.tar.xz на debian?

Tags: linux, debian, wkhtmltopdf

Действовал по инструкции https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/INSTALL.md пока она не закончилась. А именно получил папку static-build/ но пакетов .deb не обнаружил, но есть .tar.xz Разархивировал .tar.xz, но успеха не принесло.  Подскажите как завершить установку wkhtmltopdf на debian?

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: мне нужно последняя версия из исходников на  git

Answer (score 1):

Решил вспомнить как это всё делается:

```
mkdir wkhtmltopdf
cd wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt-get update
apt-get source wkhtmltopdf
sudo apt install qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev qtquick1-5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5opengl5-dev

git clone git@github.com:wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.git wkhtmltopdf-0.12.git
cd wkhtmltopdf-0.12.git
```

Эти правки приложил в [патче](https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/909226de0e849337e9ed52f9a666f993). Не значительные изменения в коде соберутся и так, но тут другой случай.

```
#cp -R ../wkhtmltopdf-0.12.1/debian/ ./ 
#rm -r debian/patches/
#nano debian/changelog #добавить новую версию нужно тут
```

Экспортируем оригинальный исходный код в архив - сборщик дебиана просил.

```
git archive --format=tar.gz master > ../wkhtmltopdf_0.12.git.orig.tar.gz
```

Дальше применяем [много правок в папке debian](https://gist.github.com/alex-eri/909226de0e849337e9ed52f9a666f993) и собираем.

```
git apply ../wkhtmltopdf-debian.patch
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

На выходе получается deb пакет под текущий дистрибутив. Лежит на папку выше.

Интересный файлик debian/watch - похоже можно както обновлять исходник средствами debian.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень полезно

Answer (score -3):

Просто переносим все что в папке есть из bin в usr/bin и будет счастье ;)

```
sudo cp /home/static-build/**/bin/* /usr/bin/
```

Comment: И получаем замусоренную систему, которой подавится apt